# Showing that the r-th moment of $u_t$ is finite

Tags: probability, inequality, martingales, time-series

I am a reading a paper, in which $u_t = \pi(L)\epsilon_t$, where $L$ is the lag operator and $\pi(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\pi_kz^k$.
Also,

[image]

It is said that the Marcinkiewicz-Zygmund inequality for martingales implies that the r-th moment of $u_t$ exists and is uniformly bounded in t. However, $u_t$ is not a martingale, thus I wonder how I could derive this result. Any comment would be appreciated even if it would not be about the MZ inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$
u_t=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \pi_k \epsilon_{t+k}
$$
The partial sums of the right hand side are the martingale that you apply MZ to, separately for each $t$.

EDIT: More details:
Define $u_{t, s}:= \sum_{k=0}^{s}\pi_k \epsilon_{t+k}$. Then $(u_{t, s})_{s}$ is a martingale because
$$
E[u_{t, s+1} | \mathcal{F}_s] = u_{t,s} + E[\pi_{s+1}\epsilon_{t+s+1} | \mathcal{F}_{s}]  = u_{t,s}
$$

Comment: I do not think that the partial sums of the RHS form a martingale. Indeed, $E(u_t | F_ {t-1} )$ is not equal to $u_{t-1}$, which is why I could not apply the MZ inequality...

Comment: Forget about the dynamics of $(u_t)_{t}$. Fix a single $t$. Then the corresponding $u_{t}$ is a sum. Each new term in that sum has expected value 0, conditioned on the previous ones, by Assumption 1.

Comment: Yes, I really actually did as you mentioned noting the fact that you changed the infinity to a fixed t. But, I cannot see why it is a martingale. Could you add just one line to let me know? That would be really appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me $\epsilon_t$ is not defined for negative t? Maybe the sum goes the opposite way of what I first had. I'll update my answer

Comment: I think $u_t=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \pi_k \epsilon_{t-k}$ and $u_{t, s}:= \sum_{k=0}^{s}\pi_k \epsilon_{t-k}$ because L is the lag operator, not the lead operator

Comment: @metric the excerpt in your question seems to indicate $\epsilon_{t}$ is only defined for positive $t$, which makes your guess impossible. You should probably edit your question with more information and with what you have so far, this seems like a waste of time atm

Comment: okay, I understand and agree with you. Thanks a lot